# Shrink a Linux guest .vdi in VirtualBox?

Tags: partition, virtualbox, disk-usage

I've seen [instructions](https://kakku.wordpress.com/2008/06/23/virtualbox-shrink-your-vdi-images-space-occupied-disk-size/) for shrinking the .vdi image for a Windows guest machine in VirtualBox 4.1.8. However, it used a tool to write zeroes to free space in the .vdi (nullfile-1.02.exe) that is for Windows only.

The page did say you should find a zerospace.c to do so in a Linux guest, but I can't find such a file any where on the Internet.

Does anyone here have experience shrinking VirtualBox Linux guests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing zeroes to free space isn't difficult (even on Windows!). Just write a file containing zeroes, until you run out of space. On unix, it's a simple shell command:

```
cat /dev/zero >fill_er_up
rm fill_er_up
```

Comment: oh yeah good idea! I'll try it and report back...